# can python source code be extracted from a single file executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe, executable

I have a Python software that I created using pyinstaller. I used pyinstaller to create a single 60 MB executable file which contains all my module dependencies.

I have used the pyinstaller code :

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed  file.py
```

I was going to release a beta version of this software to a lot of people I know. I know people can extract the source code if I create a directory containing scripts but will it still be possible for someone to extract the source code from the executable if it is just a single .exe file?

I have looked into using pyarmor and obfuscating my code before creating an executable but that would require sending a folder of some sort when I want to compile everything into a single exe file.

Comment: pyinstaller doesn't compile python to machine code (like C/C++) but it only create self-extracting .zip file with python intepreter, modules and your code in `.pyc` file. When you run this .exe then it create temporary folder, extract files and run your script. And then you can even find this folder and get all extracted files. You can read more in [How the One-File Program Works](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#how-the-one-file-program-works)

Answer (score 2):

[From the documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#hiding-the-source-code)

> The bundled app does not include any source code. However, PyInstaller bundles compiled Python scripts (.pyc files). These could in principle be decompiled to reveal the logic of your code.

So one can still reverse engineer the code, but it isn't the source code. If you want to see how the bytecode looks like you may use the [dis tool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html).

Comment: And there are tools to decompile bytecode.